# Error in displaying a doc file reading that from a document on console in java

Tags: java

I tried to display the data from a doc file on console then i got this error

```
run:
The document is really a RTF file
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DocReader.readDocFile(DocReader.java:36)
    at DocReader.main(DocReader.java:47)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

can any one explain where i went wrong

the code is
        import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;

```
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
public class DocReader {
public void readDocFile() {
File docFile = null;
WordExtractor docExtractor = null ;
WordExtractor exprExtractor = null ;
try {
docFile = new File("C:\\web.doc");

FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(docFile.getAbsolutePath());


HWPFDocument doc=new HWPFDocument(fis);

docExtractor = new WordExtractor(doc);
}
catch(Exception exep)
{
System.out.println(exep.getMessage());
}


String [] docArray = docExtractor.getParagraphText();

for(int i=0;i<docArray.length;i++)
{
if(docArray[i] != null)
System.out.println("Line "+ i +" : " + docArray[i]);
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
DocReader reader = new DocReader();
reader.readDocFile();
}
}
```

Comment: It would help to see the code around line 36 of DocReader.java to help you diagnose what went wrong.  You're using an object that has not been instantiated or assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The document is really a RTF file

That's a typical message of an `IllegalArgumentException` from the `HWPFDocument` constructor. To the point it means that the supplied file is *actually* a (Wordpad) RTF file whose `.rtf` extension has incorrectly been renamed to `.doc`.

Supply a *real* MS Word `.doc` file instead and fix your code to **not** continue the flow when an exception has occurred. You need to throw it.

Comment: How to catch this kind of exception. Because sometime I am getting eception as StringIndexOutOfBoundsException and some time i get it as NegativeArraySizeException.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the file in some Document program like Microsoft Office. Now save the same file with "Save As" option and choose .doc format.

Answer (score 0):

That means, at line 36 of DocReader.java file, you are trying to invoke an API from an object but the object is not being created yet. So, the solution is to create an instance of the class first before making that API invocation.

**UPDATE**

My hunch tells me the `NullPointerException` happens at `docExtractor.getParagraphText()` because the `docExtractor` doesn't get initialized properly. Instead of swallowing the exception, print the stacktrace to figure out the actual problem, like this:-

```
try {
    ...
}
catch(Exception exep) {
    exep.printStackTrace(); // do this
}
```

Comment: can i post the code what i did so that u can tell me where i went wrong

Comment: Yes...i got it i gave Rich text file instead word file